# EF7 Load Child of entity in List

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity relationship as follows:

```
public class Incident
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public List<Equipment> EquipmentAssignments { get; set; }

}

public class Equipment
{
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }         
    public Incident Incident { get; set; }
    public Designator Designator { get; set; }//I WANT TO INCLUDE THIS
}
```

I am trying to include "Designator" for every equipment in "EquipmentAssignments" and return this list. I am trying the following:

```
 Incident tmp = _context.Incidents
                        .Where(x => x.Id == incid)
                        .Include(x => x.EquipmentAssignments)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Select(s => s.Designator)).First();
```

But I get the following error:

> Additional information: The properties expression 'x => {from
>   Equipment s in x select [s].Designator}' is not valid. The expression
>   should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When
>   specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

I have tried using an anonymous type `.ThenInclude(x => x.Select(s => new { s.Designator})` to no avail and am not sure how to accomplish what I need. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a select in ThenInclude. This is the ThenInclude syntax:

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<TPreviousProperty>> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class;
```

Just remove the select and everything will working fine!

```
  var tmp = myConext.Incidents
          .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
          .Include(x => x.EquipmentAssignments)
          .ThenInclude(x => x.Designator).First();
```